# Is it possible to offset a tab with fseek?

Tags: c, io, fseek

I'm trying to parse a header for an archive file and I need to skip tabs. I've been trying to use `fseek()` to do this, but I can't determine if it's even possible.

Here's an example, though I'm sure the syntax is incorrect:

`fseek(stream, (long)"\t", SEEK_CUR);`

I need to use a method to move the file pointer, because I need to skip around the file and pull the file name out of each header (making a table of the contents of an archive.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- for `fseek` you specify a *distance* to move, not something for it to search for.

To skip tabs, you typically read a character, and if it's a tab just ignore it and read another character.

Comment: I see... This could help. Thank you!